# How to "append" new field/data into an object without creating a new class nor modifying the class?

Tags: java

I have a method which calculates an integer for every row in a bean `MyPeriod`. I don't want to change the class MyPeriod, to create a new class or to have two lists but I need to return some list which contains the list of MyPeriod with a new column. What is the ways to deal with this issue?

```
public ??? bindNewColumn (List<MyPeriod> periods) {
   List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();
   for (MyPeriod period : periods) {
      newList.add(calculation(period));
   }

   return ???;
}
```

Comment: What is the issue? List<Integer> ? Maybe you mean a map?

Comment: return a map instead with Period as key and calculation as value?

Comment: @user3487063 : it would be terrible for lisibility.

Comment: Just create a new class..

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking

Comment: If your classes will allow *dynamic* field and data then change into a `Map<String, Object>` but you have to accept the consequences of this bad design.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Could you explain why is a map a bad solution, please?

Comment: Because you can store whatever and then deal with whatever is stored there. It may be an `Integer`, a `String`, an `UnknownClassFromOuterProjectThatWantsToMessHere`... yes, whatever. Because of this flexibility when adding data, there's a tradeoff when consuming it and *crossing your fingers* about this `Object value` can be consumed via `toString()` in a good way.

Answer (score 2):

You have listed the good alternatives - creating a new class and changing `MyPeriod`.

If you want a bad one, you could return an array, and let your callers assume that it has two items:

```
// This is a very dirty approach. Do not use in production.
public List[] bindNewColumn (List<MyPeriod> periods) {
    ...
    return new List[] { periods, newList };
}
```

If you know that all periods in `List<MyPeriod>` are different, and also that `MyPeriod` implements robust `hashCode()` and `equals()`, you could use `LinkedHashMap<MyPeriod,Integer>` to establish your mappings:

```
public LinkedHashMap<MyPeriod,Integer> bindNewColumn (List<MyPeriod> periods) {
    LinkedHashMap<MyPeriod,Integer> res = new LinkedHashMap<MyPeriod,Integer>();
    for (MyPeriod period : periods) {
        res.put(period, calculation(period));
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JDK7 or later, you can use javafx.util.Pair :

```
public Pair<List<MyPeriod>,List<Integer>> bindNewColumn (List<MyPeriod> periods) {
    ...
    return new Pair<List<MyPeriod>,List<Integer>>(periods,newList);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With a [`Pair`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html).

```
public List<Pair<MyPeriod, Integer>> bindNewColumn(List<MyPeriod> periods) {
   final List<Pair<MyPeriod, Integer>> newList = new ArrayList<>();
   for (MyPeriod period : periods) {
      newList.add(Pair.of(period, calculation(period)));
   }

   return newList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Map<MyPeriod, Integer> bindNewColumn (List<MyPeriod> periods) {
       Map<MyPeriod, Integer> map = new HashMap<MyPeriod, Integer>();
       for (MyPeriod period : periods) {
           map.put(period, calculation(period));
       }
       return map;
    }
```

Comment: This could lead to trouble if `MyPeriod` are not unique in the list

Comment: Yes, agreed. Best is to create a new class that can hold MyPeriod and calculated value .